# Iteration between dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two form fields that are storing a date output from a previous script, each input yearstart and yearend are populated with a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. The script is triggered by an nested onchange function, in that populating the two boxes by selecting a year from another dropdown, then triggers the nested function to populate the second dropdown select item.

```
<input type="text" name="yearstart" id="yearstart" value="" readonly/>
<input type="text" name="yearend" id="yearend" value="" readonly/>
<select id="weekselect"></select>

<script>
    function getWeeks() {
        document.getElementById("weekselect").innerHTML = "";

        var yearstart = new Date(document.getElementById('yearstart').value);
        var yearend = new Date(document.getElementById('yearend').value);
        var iDate = new Date(yearstart);

        while (iDate < yearend) {
            var newele = document.createElement('option');
            newele.text = toJSONLocal(iDate);
            document.getElementById('weekselect').appendChild(newele);
            iDate.setDate(iDate.getDate() + 7)
        }
    }
</script>
```

it's working, however it's sadly only working if I select a year who's value is greater than the one already selected, so 2015, 2016 then works, but I then also get two years worth of dates not one, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I can only surmise that the script is firing before the values are updated, but the order in which the nested scripts execute should prevent that.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: One comment, I don't think `new Date(...)` will properly parse `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I think you'll need to show more code for us to see why it's firing too early..,

Comment: it does seem to work, however by removing it the results populating the dropdown are unchanged :(

Comment: I do not understand/follow what that means.

Comment: I put the whole sequence into a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hevp9oL7

Comment: I cannot access jsfiddle from where I am. Hopefully someone else can see it. Or you could try adding the full code snippet to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare 2 Date objects, use `.getTime()` to get the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

working code:

```
while (iDate.getTime() < yearend.getTime()) {
```

However, DOM manipulation is sometimes not synced with JS runtime, so `.value` of input may return wrong date. You passed some arguments to functions yet never used it.

Check out my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/atao634u/

```
function getDates() {
  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  year = new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (year.getDay() == 0) {
  day=1;
  year = year.setDate(day);
  year = new Date(year);
  }
  else if (year.getDay() != 1) {
    day = 8-(year.getDay());
    year = year.setDate(day);
    year = new Date(year);
    }
  getendDates(year);
  document.getElementById('yearstart').value = year;

}
function getendDates(yearstart) {
  var year = (document.getElementById('year').value);
  year++;
  year = new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (year.getDay() == 0) {
  day=1;
  year = year.setDate(day);
  year = new Date(year);
  }
  else if (year.getDay() != 1) {
    day = 7-(year.getDay());
    year = year.setDate(day);
    year = new Date(year);
    }
  document.getElementById('yearend').value = year;
  getWeeks(yearstart, year);
}


function getWeeks(yearstart, yearend) {
  document.getElementById("weekselect").innerHTML="";
  //var yearstart = new Date(document.getElementById('yearstart').value);
  //var yearend = new Date(document.getElementById('yearend').value);
  var iDate = new Date(yearstart);

  while (iDate.getTime() < yearend.getTime()) {
    var newele = document.createElement('option');
    newele.text = toJSONLocal(iDate);
    document.getElementById('weekselect').appendChild(newele);
    iDate.setDate(iDate.getDate() + 7)
  }
}

function toJSONLocal (date) {
    var local = new Date(date);
    local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: great answer, I hadn't considered using a time comparison as I'm more used to PHP date manupulation! Rookie mistake on my part but running the modifications has immediately worked!